# How to get data of json file in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```py
index result
0 {"ID":"000123","count":"10"}
1 {"ID":"000456","count":"23"}
2 {"ID":"000789","count":"45"}
```

This data comes from a json-file, which I read into a pandas dataframe and then only used one column of the actual read in data in order to get the data above.

What I would like to get is to split result and instead get two new columns `ID` and `count` and remove `result`.

So, the new dataframe should look like this:

```py
ID count
000123 10
000456 23
000789 45
```

Note: I want to keep the leading zeros in `ID` column, i.e. the type of the values can also remain `string`.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output of `type(df.loc[0,'result'])` is `dict` then use:

```
data=df['result'].to_list()
resultdf=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**OR**

If the output of `type(df.loc[0,'result'])` is `str` then use:

Use `apply()` method and `eval()` method:

```
data=df['result'].apply(lambda x:eval(x)).tolist()
resultdf=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now If you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output:

```
    ID  count
0   000123  10
1   000456  23
2   000789  45
```

Comment: I get: TypeError: `eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object`

Comment: Updated my answer...Kindly check now **:)**

Comment: That does it. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: For more simplicity....Again Updated my answer..Kindly have a look **:)**